# Why is this std::launder example undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, stdlaunder

This is the part of the example that I don't understand:

```cpp
struct Y
{
    int z;
};
int main()
{
    alignas(Y) std::byte s[sizeof(Y)];
    Y *q = new (&s) Y{2};
    const int f = reinterpret_cast<Y *>(&s)->z; // Class member access is undefined behavior:
                                                // reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&s) has value "pointer to s"
                                                // and does not point to a Y object
}
```

And the whole example is at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder.

I don't understand why using `reinterpret_cast<Y *>(&s)->z` is undefined behavior. We have already constructed a Y object at the so-called "pointer to s", and also reinterpreted it to `Y*`, so why does it still say that "it does not point to a Y object" ?

Comment: As far as I can see, regardless of the type, s, q and `reinterpret_cast<Y *>(&s)` have the same value.

Comment: "As far as I can see, regardless of the type, s, q and `reinterpret_cast<Y *>(&s)` have the same value" - That's irrelevant as far as determining whether something is UB. If the standard says it is UB the compiler is free to assume you don't do it and is free to generate *whatever* code it pleases. Literally *any* behaviour is acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

`&s` is a pointer to a `std::byte[sizeof(Y)]`, not a `Y`.  That means using `&s` as a `Y*` is undefined behavior because it violates the aliasing rules.  Even though there is a `Y` living there, the [rules of `reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) (specifically the Type aliasing section) don't allow you to access the object because it can't know there is actually a object there.

`std::launder` was introduced to explicitly allow you to treat the returned pointer as a valid pointer to the object, instead of a pointer to the storage the object lives in.  Essentially, it is an explicit override of the type aliasing rules.  You are telling the compiler with it that you know that pointer really does point to a valid object, and if you lied, well then you are back in undefined behavior land.

Comment: And in case anyone's wondering, the aliasing rules are largely in place to allow efficient "re-ordering" of statements that do not affect the same object (although that's not really what happens, because you're describing a program, rather than programming a computer! the compiler programs the computer for you...)

Comment: Btw, the UB can easily be fixed by using `s` correctly: Just declare `alignas(Y) unsigned char s[sizeof(Y)];` and drop the superfluous `&` operator. `s` will then decay to an `unsigned char*`, and that type is exempt from strict aliasing rules. As such, `reinterpret_cast<Y*>(s)->z` is well defined.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica No, that is still UB.  It is legal to cast an object to char/byte and read its bytes, but it is illegal to treat a storage pool as an object unless you use the pointer returned from placement new, or you use `std::launder`.

Comment: Speak for yourself ;) This is exactly why `std::launder` is required.

Comment: C++20 will make this more complicated though as a storage pool for "implicit types" can be used as if the object exists without placement new or launder.

Comment: While it is formally UB I think `std::launder` was introduced specifically to find a conforming way of doing what has been common practice for decades: Cast an "untyped" pointer to the type of an "object" we know is there or can be there, for one reason or another. One prime example is hardware access at known addresses. Another is using the memory returned by `malloc`, see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html. No compiler would produce invalid code for `int *pi = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); *pi = 1;`, even though no int exists there.